# Plotly subplots. Несколько графиков в каждом subplot

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

Задача построить в plotly subplots, который содержал бы несколько графиков в каждом subplot.
Пробовал так:

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python3  
 from plotly.subplots import make_subplots  
 import plotly.graph_objects as go  
 import numpy as np
 import pandas as pd  
 df=pd.DataFrame({'id':np.linspace(0,10,10),  
            'Y1':np.random.randn(10),'Y11':np.random.randn(10),# 2 графика первого subplot
             'Y2':np.random.randn(10),'Y22':np.random.randn(10), 2 графика второго subplot 
            'Y3':np.random.randn(10),'Y33':np.random.randn(10)  2 графика третьего subplot
             })

 trace1=go.Scatter(x=df['id'],y=df['Y1'])  
 trace2=go.Scatter(x=df['id'],y=df['Y11'])  
 data1=[trace1,trace2]  

 trace3=go.Scatter(x=df['id'],y=df['Y2'])  
 trace4=go.Scatter(x=df['id'],y=df['Y22'])
 data2=[trace3,trace4]

 trace5=go.Scatter(x=df['id'],y=df['Y3'])
 trace6=go.Scatter(x=df['id'],y=df['Y33'])
 data3=[trace5,trace6]

 fig = make_subplots(rows=3, cols=1)

 fig.append_trace(data1,row=1, col=1)
 fig.append_trace(data2,row=2, col=1)
 fig.append_trace(data3,row=3, col=1)

 fig.update_layout(height=600, width=600, title_text="Subplots")
 fig.show()
```

Но увы. Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас все почти получилось, но Плотли не умеет так передавать данные. Надо каждый трейс передавать отдельно.

Давайте немного изменим `add_trace`:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'id':np.linspace(0,10,10),  
            'Y1':np.random.randn(10),'Y11':np.random.randn(10),# 2 графика первого subplot
             'Y2':np.random.randn(10),'Y22':np.random.randn(10), # 2 графика второго subplot 
            'Y3':np.random.randn(10),'Y33':np.random.randn(10)  # 2 графика третьего subplot
             })

trace1=go.Scatter(x=df['id'],
                  y=df['Y1'])  
trace2=go.Scatter(x=df['id'],
                  y=df['Y11'])  
data1=[trace1,trace2]  


trace3=go.Scatter(x=df['id'],y=df['Y2'])  
trace4=go.Scatter(x=df['id'],y=df['Y22'])
data2=[trace3,trace4]

trace5=go.Scatter(x=df['id'],y=df['Y3'])
trace6=go.Scatter(x=df['id'],y=df['Y33'])
data3=[trace5,trace6]

fig = make_subplots(rows=3, cols=1)

for x in data1:
    fig.add_trace(x,row=1, col=1)

for x in data2:
    fig.add_trace(x,row=2, col=1)

for x in data3:
    fig.add_trace(x,row=3, col=1)


fig.update_layout(height=600, width=600, title_text="Subplots")
fig.show()
```

Наверное, можно и генераторами (что лучше для читаемости кода), но у меня с ними не завелось.

Удачи!